# Django model data consistency

Tags: django, django-models

When creating a form, you can define a bunch of methods, `clean_xyz`, to make sure the data gets forced into the correct format. Is there any way to do this on a model level?

Perhaps I can override the field setters somehow? I want it so that if I write something like

```
my_address.postal_code = 'a1b2c3'
```

It will automatically get formatted into `A1B 2C3`. Perhaps throw an exception if it can't be converted. That way I know I'll never have any malformed data in the database.

Answer (score 3):

As of Django 1.2 there's [a section in the docs that deal with the validation of models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects), I suggest you look at [Model.clean()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean).

Comment: Oh... I didn't know they added that! They don't have a `clean_FIELD()` methods like the forms do though eh? Oh well. This should work well enough. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the specifics of your situation, you could create your own custom model fields and add validation there (c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930469/django-custom-model-field-with-validation-how-to-hook-it-back-to-modelform).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe overriding save() on your model might help you out?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # do your formatting
    self.postal_code = somefancyformattingmethod()
    # save it to the database
    super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Not a bad approach. Didn't think about doing it on save.